# AJAX Redirect on Success Overriding other logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, redirect

I can't seem to get a redirect to a new page after executing AJAX success (This is in a script for jQuery Mobile). In the following code, if I do other functions other than a redirect, the sessionStorage is set as expected. When doing a redirect, the sessionStorage code is not executed. Suggestions??

```
$("#register").click(function () {

    var formData = $("#registerUser").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "file.php",
        //dataType:'json',
        cache: false,
        data: formData,
        //success: onSuccess,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == 'success') {

                //execute some code here
                var someValue = (data.id);
                sessionStorage.setItem('someValue', someValue);

            } else if (data.status == 'error') $("#notification").text(data.message);
        },

        complete: function () {
            window.location.replace('newPage.html');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Note that this is a problem in Chrome only. In Firefox everything works as expected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured this one out myself -- you have to use JQM redirect: `$.mobile.changePage('newPage.html');`

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data.status == 'success') {

        //execute some code here
        var someValue = (data.id);
        sessionStorage.setItem('someValue', someValue);

        // redirect after success
        $.mobile.changePage('newPage.html');

    } else if (data.status == 'error') {
        $("#notification").text(data.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no mention of JQM on the original question.

Comment: Thanks Hugo -- I've edited the question to indicate it is for JQM

Answer (score 1):

Your success and complete are conflicting. Both will execute when it completes. One will redirect. Move the redirect code into success to make it redirect after it does the other things.

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data.status == 'success') {

        //execute some code here
        var someValue = (data.id);
        sessionStorage.setItem('someValue', someValue);

        // redirect after success
        window.location.replace('newPage.html');

    } else if (data.status == 'error') {
        $("#notification").text(data.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually tried that first with the same result. The page redirects without saving the sessionStorage values (chrome only)

Comment: And everything works fine (in Chrome) if you take out the redirect, right?

Comment: Yes -- the sessionStorage is set fine without the redirect in there.